# java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction exception occur in MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, struts

I am Using a table name "test" in **MYSQL** that is lock during a transaction T1 that will be complete with in 20 minutes.  When I am updating this table by another transaction T2  within these 20 minutes . I am getting an exception:-

```
11:58:38,584 ERROR [STDERR] java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
11:58:38,584 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2928)
11:58:38,584 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1571)
11:58:38,584 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:1124)
11:58:38,584 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:676)
```

Please provide me the solution that how can I do this transaction T2 without getting this exception?

Is it right to update the value of **innodb_lock_wait_timeout** in mysql database for solve this exception. I look forward for getting any useful solution for this problem .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Updating the value of innodb_lock_wait_timeout is *not* the right way to solve this problem. For starters, you it sounds like you would need to update it to 20 minutes, which would be ridiculous.

innodb_lock_wait_timeout has a default of 50 seconds - this is the length of time T2 will wait for access to a table locked by T1 before giving up (and resulting in the exception you are seeing).

What is your T2 transaction doing? If it is performing reads only (i.e. not writing to your table "test") then you *could* change the database's isolation level to "read uncommitted" so that T2 can read the uncommitted data. However, IMO this is a hack you should avoid.

Instead, you should consider your design/implementation. To have a transaction that is open and holding a row lock for 20 minutes is asking for trouble in a multi-threaded environment (such as a webapp).

Does your archiving activity (which takes 20 minutes) have to be in one transaction? An obvious way to solve this problem would be to commit after every statement or to break it into more reasonably sized transactions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this transaction T1(hold lock on various tables) will execute for archiving purpose through event scheduler once in a day.I want to do some other activity on these tables during that transaction. It is mandatory to run this transaction so please let me know that is there any way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Transaction T2 is doing read and write both kind of transaction.

Comment: Does the archiving activity have to be in one transaction? An obvious way to solve this problem would be to commit after every statement or to break it into more reasonably sized transactions.

Comment: Yes . There is a condition that's why I can not commit the transaction after a bunch of query execution or every statement. Please let me know if there is any solution for this.

Comment: I can do with the help of explicitly table locking . but I am not able to use locking queries in stored procedure.

Answer (score -10):

Restart your local mysql to avoid this type of problem

Comment: This worked, why -1 ? Do you know how many people understand the accepted answer ? None...

Comment: Rather than downvoting my answer, why don't you specify what you don't understand about it? Maybe also explain why you think restarting MySql is a valid solution to this issue, or even practical, on a production server?

Comment: @Siddharth Lies! Anyway, if you don't understand it you don't understand it but when you do you do. Come on! Anyway, this post states that you would avoid the problem by restarting, even though that is a temporary workaround to the problem and does not avoid anything from happening again. If you understand this one it is because you aren't reading it ;)

Comment: Cant really argue when you are wrong, I take it back guys :). I'll reverse my down vote. Please edit the answer with the justification that restarting on  production is impossible, hence understanding the root cause is important even before considering restarting. Thanks.